# One to Many Relationship: Describing the Tables

Tags: foreign-key, relations

If we have two tables in a One-to-Many relation ship, is there a standard name to properly refer to the tables?

For example if I have a table of `books`, and a table of `authors` (ignoring for now the possibility of joint authorship), how can we generically refer to the two tables in the relationship.

I have come to refer to the `authors` as the **Parent** table, and the `books` as the **Child** table, arguing that the books may be regarded as the brain-children of the authors. This description doesn’t work as well for, say, a table of `sales` and `saleitems`.

I have sometimes seen them referred to as the `one` and `many` tables, but I wonder whether there is a more useful way of referring to them.

Is there a standard way of referring to the tables?

Comment: An `order` can have 1 or many (ignore the case for the moment of an order where every item has been cancelled for one reason or another) `order_line` records (I favour singular table names - though not perhaps for `order`...) - it's a one-to-many relationship. A give order line must have an order associated with it! You cannot (in any sort of a decent system) have order_lines with no orders. "one-to-many" is the perfect way in which to refer to such relationships. Why are you not satisfied with the term one-to-many? For books and authors BTW, it'd have to be many-to-many.

Comment: FYI, your example of books and authors without joint authorship is unfortunate, as books-authors with joint-authorship is a clssic example of Many-to-Many used very often in database textbooks, lectures, and documentation. Its use here is distracting and confusing.

Comment: @BasilBourque Appreciated, but I simply want to make a point about a simple one-to-many relationships. I do, in fact, use joint authorship when trying to introduce associative tables.

Comment: @Vérace I’m happy to call the _relationship_ one-to-many. It’s a question of how to refer to the tables. For example, in a join between the tables, it is the number of rows in the `many` table which governs the number of results (the same if all the foreign keys have values, or if it’s one of the outer joins). I wondered whether there is an alternative way to refer to the `many` table, other than, say, the `child` table.

Answer (score 2):

The typical nomenclature for this type of table design would be ["class-subclass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subclass_(computer_science)).  In your example of `Books` and `Authors`, `Books` is a subclass of the `Author` class.  Any book automatically has an author, since no book can ever be written without having an author write it.  Same goes for `Sales` and `SalesItems`; each `SalesItem` must have an associated `Sales` object.

However, "parent-child" may be employed where it makes sense.  As is so often typical, the answer is It Depends™.

Using nomenclature that makes sense for the specific domain in question, and is easily and readily understood by the stakeholders, ensures future comprehension.

One-to-many is a typical term used to describe the *relationship* between rows in each table.  The relationship might also be one-to-one or many-to-one or even many-to-many, depending on domain requirements.